# Trying to find a contradiction for a certain proof (basic)

Tags: proof-writing, proof-explanation

I'm doing proof by contradiction for the first time and I understand the concept now, but I can't find a contradiction in my negation.

I'm trying to conclude $\neg n$

$h\wedge\neg r$

$(h\wedge n)\to r$

---

$~n$

My negations are:

$\neg h\vee r$

$h\wedge n\wedge\neg r$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$h\land \neg r$$  $$(h\land n) \rightarrow r$$

---

$$(h\land \neg r)\rightarrow\neg r$$
$$(h\land \neg r)\rightarrow h$$
$$\neg r \rightarrow \neg(h\land n)$$
$$(\neg(h\land n)\land h)\rightarrow\neg n$$

Comment: Awesome! this format was easiest to understand

Comment: @HowardP, great!  Please see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)  You can "accept" an answer by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 2):

The negations of the two premises are not useful. You need to negate the sentence you are trying to prove, but the premises you use as they are, like this:

Assume $n$. From $h\wedge\neg r$ follows $h$. Infer $h\wedge n$. Use modus ponens to infer $r$. From $h\wedge\neg r$ follows also $\neg r$. Contradiction. Conclude $\neg n$.

Comment: Ooh, just beat me to it. :-)

Comment: Thank you! Clarifyng that i need to negate the sentence made it alot more clear

Answer (score 1):

1. $h \land \neg r \qquad \qquad$ Premise
2. $ (h \land n) \rightarrow r \qquad$ Premise
3. $\qquad n \qquad \qquad \qquad$ Assumption (for the proof by contradiction)
4. $\qquad h \qquad \qquad \qquad$ Simplification 1
5. $\qquad h \land n\qquad \qquad$. Conjunction 3,4
6. $\qquad r \qquad \qquad \qquad$ Modus Ponens 2,5
7. $\qquad \neg r \qquad \qquad$ Simplification 1
8. $\qquad \bot \qquad \qquad$ Contradiction 6,7
9. $\neg n \qquad \qquad$ Proof by Contradiction 3-8

Answer (score 0):

Remember, proof by contradiction works by assuming the negation of your *conclusion*, and inferring a contradiction - it has nothing to do with negating your premises.

Think about the problem in terms of the intuitive logic of the situation. Your premises say the following: first, "$h$ is true, and $r$ is not"; second, "if $h$ and $n$ are both true, then $r$ is true". Intuitively, if $n$ were true (the negation of your conclusion), we would have that $h$ and $n$ are both true (using the first half of the first premise). So $r$ is true (using the second premise). But $r$ is false (using the second half of the first premise), which means we now have $r \wedge \neg r$, a contradiction.

Now, the challenge is just taking those steps and converting them into formal logic.

Comment: This really solidifies my understanding! thank you